# How to create SSRS 2012 folders with powershell script

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are trying to automate the migration of SQL server reports from a number of slow servers to one much faster server.   We need to move our clients one at a time.  We have a script that exports all of the reports, data sources and the folder structure.

we have managed to amend scripts to recreate all the data sources and report files if the folder structure is in place.  We took this article as a basis

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2013/02/12/deploying-ssrs-artefacts-using-powershell-simply.aspx

what we are unable to achieve is to automatically recreate the folder structure.

The script we have creates a list of folders as so:

```
\client_live
\client_live\AccountTransaction
\client_live\BudgetApproval
\client_live\Custom
\client_live\NominalReporting
\client_live\OnlineReports
\client_live\Product
\client_live\Sales
\client_live\Stock
\client_live\Stock\updates
\client_live\Stock\backorder
\client_live\Suppliers
\client_live\TransactionReporting
\client_live\Transactions
```

We can reverse the \ to / and using split-path collect sections of each folder path.

Each client has different folder paths and the number of subfolders differs per client.

We know we need to create a folder client_live then its sub folders and so on.

The issue is how to loop through the list we have and pass the relevant details into this section of code, replacing the hardcoded entries for "NewFolder"  and "/" with appropriate values from the list

```
$type = $Proxy.GetType().Namespace
$datatype = ($type + '.Property')

$property =New-Object ($datatype);
$property.Name = “NewFolder”
$property.Value = “NewFolder”

$numproperties = 1
$properties = New-Object ($datatype + '[]')$numproperties 
$properties[0] = $property;

$newFolder = $proxy.CreateFolder(“NewFolder”, “/”, $properties)
```

This is what we use to generate our list.

```
# script to create folders in SQL 2012 RS
#
# taken from http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2013/02/12/deploying-ssrs-artefacts-using-powershell-simply.aspx
# and amended.
# Connect to SSRS Webservice - assume we are on the server used.
$ReportServerUri = "http://localhost/ReportServer//ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl"
$global:proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential ;
# amend the following line to point to your files.
$source = "C:\import\Lime"
$cut=$source.length

$result=gci -r $source | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName }

foreach ($item in $result)
{
# first input to  to have correct data source.
$list=$item.substring($cut)
# echo out just to validate what we have so far.
echo $list
}
```

Our powershell skills are all self taught so please excuse any crudities in our code.

regards

spencer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a recursive function to walk the folder structure. You have the api calls to get the properties for items in ssrs so you can use those in a function similar to:

```
function RecurseSSRSDirectory ([string]$directory){

    $items = <--Function to get assets in $directory

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item type is report) {
            //do something with report
        }
        elseif  ($item type is dataset) {
            //do something with dataset
        }elseif ($item type is folder) {
            //Create folder here
            Recurse $item.Path
        }

    }
}
```